# Is this considered RESTful?

Tags: asp.net, wcf-rest

I am writing a simple web page for our existing web site that will only be used by the web site admin to delete all images from a certain directory on the server. He would browse to this page from his web browser (not to be consumed by any external services as of right now). I was thinking of creating another ASPX page (obviously not linked from or to anywhere) that implemented this. Is this considered a RESTful API? If not, what would be, and would it be a more elegant solution than what I'm proposing?

I realize this is an extremely simplistic example, but I'm trying to understand what RESTful really means and if it would benefit our existing infrastructure in any meaningful way, so that's kind of the purpose of this question.

Our website is written entirely in ASP.NET 2.0 WebForms.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your URL structure. a classic REST API call would be to, say:
/images/delete

You would then send a Post as DELETE or just GET or POST to this to do what you need. That's more the RESTful way. REST isn't so much what you are doing with the method as the structure of that method. I hope that makes sense :).

Comment: OK, I understand that. Is that something that's easy to do with WebForms (given that the URL path is directly related to the path of the files on the server)? That seems far simpler in MVC where you can explicitly define the path of each function and/or view...